# How to handle 2 widget events to control a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, ipywidgets

I am trying to use 2 ipywidgets to control a dataframe and refresh as a change the 2 ipywidgets.

Create a new column (Check_value) that shifts down the Values column by the value in widget A

Filter and show only the rows where the Check_value is bigger than the Value column by the value in widget B

The dataframe :

Dates    |  Values 
Day 1    |  5 
Day 2    |  9 
Day 3    |  14 
Day 4    |  40 
Day 5    |  80

```
## Widget A 
A = widgets.IntSlider(
value=1,
min=1,
max=30,
step=1)

## Widget B

B = widgets.IntSlider(
value=1,
min=1,
max=30,
step=1)

out = widgets.Output()  

## Processing 
def common_processing(period, filters):
  out.clear_output()

  with out:
    df = pd.read_csv(data.csv)
    df['Dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Dates'])
    df['check_value'] = df['Value'].shift(-period)
    df['delta'] = df['check_value'] - df['Value']
    display(df[df['delta'] > filters])   

def A_eventhandler(change):
  common_processing(change.new, B.value)

def B_eventhandler(change):
  common_processing(A.value, change.new)

A.observe(A_eventhandler, names='value')
B.observe(B_eventhandler, names='value')

display(A)
display(B)
```

The data frame displayed does not change with changes in the widget values.

Answer (score 0):

I tried running your code, the A_eventhandler function is never called when you change the widget value (you can check this by running `print(change)` before the `common_processing` call.)

The reason is your `names` keyword needs to be a list, rather than a string. So try:

```py
    A.observe(A_eventhandler, names=['value'])
    B.observe(B_eventhandler, names=['value'])
```

When I set up an `observe` on a widget, I always do it without any filtering first, just printing the result in the observed function. Then you can add keywords to filter down to just the events and values you need.

Also, don't forget to `display(out)` somewhere in your code, as you are capturing the output here. Otherwise you will never see anything!